# Terminate one batch script after other is closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have 3 cmd scripts running. If one ends, the other have to stop too. How can I implement this?

Script one start.
Script one start script 2 and 3.
Now they have to check each other if other scripts are still running. 
If script 2 crashes, 1 and 3 have to terminate themselves.

Comment: Use Powershell. Have each script write its PID to a different file. Whenever each script checks to see if the others are running, it can use the PID to find out. See `tasklist /?` for more information.

Comment: Are you really using **MS-DOS**, the OS from the 1980s??